# How to refresh the content of a tab in an actionBar (Android)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

Here the summary of my 'project' on Android 4.x and the problem I can't solve:

i have an actionBar with 2 tabs (i know it is deprecated):

```
...
Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();    
Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();
ActionBar.Tab tab1, tab2;
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("tab1");
tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("tab2");
tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab1));
tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab2));
actionBar.addTab(tab1);
actionBar.addTab(tab2);
...
```

I would like to change the fragment of a tab and refresh what the user sees, doing that in a method (not only when the tab is (re)selected).

It sounds simple, but impossible to find a easy way to do that.

After many fails, this is what I try (i remove the tab and add it with a new fragment):

```
void myMethod () {
getActionBar().removeTabAt(0);
tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("tab3");
tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab3));
getActionBar().addTab(tab1, 0);
...
```

And then this awful thing to desesperatly try to update what is seen...

```
...
getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(tab1.getPosition()+1);
getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(tab1.getPosition());
}
```

Everything goes as wanted, except that the reselected tab1 is empty... :(

If I select with my finger tab2 then tab1 (so manually in place of programmaticaly), then tab1 appears as wanted...

So, how can I change programmaticaly the content of a tab and refresh what is seen in an actionBar?

Already a big thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You should depend on **TabListener** methods, don't do `getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem()`. There are good code samples on the Internet.

1)  Google webpage @ [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). Code snippet:

```
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // show the given tab
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // hide the given tab
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // probably ignore this event
    }
};
```

Notes: Refresh your data in `onTabSelected()`. You may check for tags or text in `tab` parameter.

2) Another good link for you @ [Android Fragment Tabs Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragment-tabs-example/). Code snippet from the link:

```
public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment fragment;
    public TabListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }
    // When a tab is tapped, the FragmentTransaction replaces
    // the content of our main layout with the specified fragment;
    // that's why we declared an id for the main layout.
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment);
    }
```

Notes: Again, refresh your data in `onTabSelected()`.  I have to warn you that TabListener is deprecated in the new Lollipop API.

**EDIT**:
Sample code to set Tabs to the correct Fragments.

```
// Setting tab listeners.
bmwTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(bmwFragmentTab));
toyotaTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(toyotaFragmentTab));
fordTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(fordFragmentTab));
```

Good luck and have fun...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I edited my question to specify that i want to do the changes in a method (not only when a tab is selected). Could you expand your explanation to this case? A big thanks!

Comment: @ArthurDent, Welcome to Stackoverflow (SO). Pls read the SO tutorial on how to use this site @ http://stackoverflow.com/tour . You will get rep points this way.  I did add more sample code under EDIT. Basically at this point, you will have to try the code yourself. The sample code at the links provided is working code that you asked for. If you think my posted answer is helpful, you may select it as the best answer by clicking on the checkmark symbol.  Afterwards, you can post another question after your attempts and progress.

Comment: thank you. I read all that documentation hundred times but it doesn't give me my solution since ontabselected() is called (only) when the tab is selected. My wish is to change (all) the content of the tab from a method which can be called anytime. Due to this (f*$%ng) deprecation, i'm considering to change my code to use proper methods. Idon't 'need' to swipe between tabs, just 3 tabs and to be able to change the content of one from a method. Do you (or anybody) know the best (= simple, not deprecated and compatible with android 4&5 devices) way to achieve this?